# How to calculate area of an ellipse based on its formula?

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

How can I determine the area of a half-ellipse if all that is given is $y = \sqrt{1-n^2x^2}$? I have tried both geometry and calculus, but without convincing results…

Thank you

Comment: This equation corresponds to half of an ellipse if I am not wrong ...

Comment: The area of an ellipse is equal to $\pi ab$, $a,b$ being the lengths of the semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipse.

Comment: @damien
you are right: I have edited accordingly...

Comment: Try to manipulate the formula of the ellipse to make apparent its two lengths, i.e. try to find its canonic form

Answer (score 1):

[image: Figure]

The area of the half-ellipse is given by the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} ydx=2\int_0^{1/n}\sqrt{1-n^2x^2}\ dx$

There is a formula for solving integrals of the form $\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\ dx$, but we will not use it directly. Instead, substitute $nx=\sin\theta\implies dx=\frac{\cos\theta}nd\theta$

$\implies A=\frac2n\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta d\theta=\frac1n\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos2\theta+1) d\theta=\frac\pi{2n}$

Can you now show similarly that the area enclosed by the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is equal to $\pi ab$?

Answer (score 0):

With the use of generalized polar coordinates 
\begin{aligned}x&=ar\cos t\\
y&=br\sin t\end{aligned}
where $a=\frac 1n,\; b=1,\; t \in [0,\pi]\; \text{and}\; r\in [0,1]$ in the given case. The Jacobian is ${r\over n}$ and the area
$$\cal{A}=\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1 1\cdot {r\over n}\;dr \;dt=\frac{\pi}{2n}$$